# Why does metaclass with object base raise metaclass conflict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Why in the code below does metaclass with object base raise metaclass conflict exception?

> "metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases"

```
class M_A(object): pass
class A(object, metaclass = M_A): pass
```

So does another code:

```
class M_A(list): pass
class A(object, metaclass = M_A): pass
```

I understand that the cpython will interpret the above code as:

```
A = M_A.__new__(M_A, 'A', (object,), {})
```

What confuses me is that  the base class of A is *object*, and any class is subclass of *object*. This error is so strange. 
What's wrong with me?

Comment: `M_A` is not a subclass of a metaclass of any base class of `A`. `class M_A(type): pass` will probably work.

Comment: What confuses me is that  the base class of A is *object*, and any class is subclass of *object*.  Is M_A(list)  a subclass of a metaclass of any base class of A? I think it is.

Comment: @ahui `M_A(list)` is a subclass of `object`, yes. But that's not what the error message is about. `M_A` has to be a subclass of `object`'s _metaclass_, which is `type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at this error message:

> metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

This is a little confusing, so let's take a look at what's what:

- The *"derived class"* is `A`.
- The *"metaclass of a derived class"* `A` is `M_A`.
- `A`'s base class is `object`, therefore *"the metaclasses of all its bases"* is `type` - because `type` is `object`'s metaclass.

This is the problem - `object`'s metaclass is `type`, but `A`'s metaclass is `M_A`. Since `M_A` isn't a subclass of `type`, python doesn't know which metaclass to use for `A` and throws an error.

---

To fix this, change the parent class of `M_A` to `type`:

```
class M_A(type): pass
class A(object, metaclass = M_A): pass

# no errors thrown
```